# UITableView is asking for a ghost section after a batch row and section deletion, causing a crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uitableview

I have myself a UITableView which is initialized with a total of 8 sections, most sections only have 1 row but a few have 2. I am doing a batch deletion of rows in the table. I realize that some of these rows are the only rows in their section, so instead of deleting those rows, I am trying to delete their sections. I am trying to go from 8 sections (total of 12 rows in all) down to a remaining 2 sections (1 row in each).

Before I am calling into the table to delete the rows and sections, I am making sure that all the rows and sections are out of my data source. My 2d array is being updated properly so that the new size of the array is 2, with each subarray holding just 1. With that in mind, everything in the data source is correctly updated before performing the actual deletion.

pretty simple code to do the deletion

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView deleteSections:sectionsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

<strike>However, I get a crash at the `[self.tableView endUpdates]` call. Specifically, the crash is
`*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070`</strike>

Edit: This crash was incorrect, I am crashing because of an index out of bounds error, which will be described below

Using a debugger to step through the `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` and the `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` reassure me that my data source is correct, returning 2 sections and each section with 1 row. HOWEVER, this is the weird part.

In the `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` delegate implementation, the table view passes me a section=0, then a section=1 (which is expected), and it should end there. but it doesnt, it then passes me a section=6.

I have no idea where the 6 is coming from. All the numbers in my data source are correct. Anyone have any thoughts as to how I can debug this better? Or any ideas as to what is going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide the initial list of index paths and the values of `indexPathsToRemove` and `sectionsToRemove`? And make sure you're not deleting rows in deleted sections because it can crash the table.

Comment: You should get more information from that Assertion failure if you remove your exception breakpoint and let it run. Could you post that?

Comment: Will do timothy. I am making sure that no rows are being deleted out of the sections however. one thing that im wondering is if i delete a number of sections, do the index paths change so that now the rows I am deleting are no longer valid? will get back to you on the list.

Comment: here is the list of initial index paths: [0,0] [1,0] [2,0] [2,1] [3,0] [4,0] [4,1] [5,0] [6,0] [7,0] [7,1] [7,2]. indexPathsToRemove = [2,1]. sectionsToRemove = 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Comment: @kball I apologize, the crash i posted above must have been something else. the crash itself is happening because in the table delegate call numberOfRowsInSection is passing in a 'ghost' 6 section, which doesnt exist in my data source, which is causing an index out of bounds crash

Comment: forgot to @TimothyMoose

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your scenario using [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) and didn't get a crash. Here is [the source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2183704/Ghost%20Section%20Test.zip) if you want to take a look. If you step through the method `performBatchUpdatesOnTableView` in `TLIndexPathUpdates`, you can see exactly what batch updates are performed. When I stepped through myself, the only difference I could see from what you've described is that sections are being deleted before rows. I tried reversing the order (deleting rows before sections) and it did crashed. I did not see a ghost section, though.

So, I would try deleting sections before rows. If that doesn't work, I think the problem lies somewhere outside of the information you've provided. If you can post more of your source or a sample project, I'll take another look.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Still havent narrowed down where this problem could be happening. Its a fairly complex system I am trying to fit this into so I would not be surprised if something else is going on. If anything changes I will be sure to let you know. I would give you some rep but I am new and cant just yet. Thanks again for the time!